# deleting certs from the "other people" certificate store

Tags: powershell, vbscript, certificate, x509certificate2

I have been doing some research to see if there is a way to script this functionality and I cant seem to find **where** these certs are actually stored. I see the other articles on "deleting certificates from store", but I think these are causing me more confusion.

If I run a search like `get-childitem -path cert:\CurrentUser`, I don't see the `Other People` location. But, I am able to see the location in `certmgr.msc`. I have also checked the reg locations outlined here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783813(WS.10).aspx and can't seem to find the location either.

So, I guess my question is as follows:

1. Can a script be built to go into this location and do a full clean-up?
2. Where are these certs actually installed on the local system?

Thank you, and I apologize if this seems a little erratic. This has been making my head spin for almost two hours. Thanks.

Comment: Is the "Other People" location by any chance empty?

Comment: Mathias- No, I have roughly 20-40 certs located in this location, expired and current. This location is used as a "cache" location, so it gets populated automatically.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the AddressBook directory of the CurrentUser store. Do a `gci Cert:\CurrentUser\AddressBook` and I bet you see the exact same certificates as you do in the 'Other People' section of certmgr.msc. If you do not want to keep any of those certificates deleting them all is as simple as:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\AddressBook | Remove-Item
```

They will all be deleted if you do that, so please do so with caution. Just want to get rid of expired certificates? Add a where statement like this:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\AddressBook | Where{$_.NotAfter -lt [datetime]::Now} | Remove-Item
```

That one would only remove expired certificates.

Anyway, you want `Cert:\CurrentUser\AddressBook`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, performed the search in addressbook and no results are shown.

Screen shot of cert store- http://postimg.org/image/d1rgrs8rt/

screen shot or PS return- http://postimg.org/image/pxccyz4zv/

Comment: Well, let's try this then... look at how many certs are in that folder in certmgr.msc and then do `gci cert:\currentuser -recurse | Group PSParentPath|select Count,Name` and look for the group that has the right amount of certificates in it.

Comment: The correct container name is `TrustedPeople`. I edited your response appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I performed the path and the command was unable to group bu "PSPatrentPath". I was able to do a recursive search useing "gci cert:\currentuser -recurse" and this shows me root certs, but doesnt show me anything in the "Other People" location. I must be missing something here...

Comment: In your comment you misspelled "PSParentPath" as "PSPatrentPath" so that may be part of the issue. You should be able to copy and paste the code in my comment and run it without issues.

Comment: Sorry, that was a misspelling from my typing back to the site. Tried it again and still the same error, this time I used cp paste as you advised.

Comment: You must be using an older version of PowerShell is all I can think. Let me think about it and I'll see if I can find another way.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I performed a $PSVersionTable.PSversion, here are the results,

Major, 3  Minor,  0  Build, -1  Revision, -1

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Internet options had the remove button disabled even on safe boot with internet. Cert manager was not finding it at all. Could not remove through code either. No internet answer helped. Get-ChildItem worked like a charm. Double upvote if I could