# Import *.der certificate to 'Other People' store

Tags: powershell, certificate

I'm able to import certificates to all stores using PowerShell.

For example this way:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\temp\SomeCertificate.crt" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

I can get all stores this way using powershell:

```
set-location cert:
```

and

```
dir .\\LocalMachine\
```

giving me these options:

Name : TestSignRoot

Name : ClientAuthIssuer

Name : Remote Desktop

Name : Root

Name : TrustedDevices

Name : CA

Name : TrustedAppRoot

Name : eSIM Certification Authorities

Name : AuthRoot

Name : Windows Live ID Token Issuer

Name : TrustedPublisher

Name : AAD Token Issuer

Name : FlightRoot

Name : TrustedPeople

Name : addressbook

Name : My

Name : SmartCardRoot

Name : Trust

Name : Disallowed

Name : Homegroup Machine Certificates

Name : REQUEST

But I'm unable to import to the 'Other People' store:

[image]

How can I import to the 'Other People' store?
Something like:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\temp\SomeCertificate.crt" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\OtherPeople
```

UPDATE:
Its **AddressBook**.
But this isn't available if there isn't a certificate installed of this type. (Like on a clean windows 10)

How can I import the certificate to AddressBook when its not already available as a store?
Can I create that store manually and then import the certificate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deleting certs from the "other people" certificate store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802019/deleting-certs-from-the-other-people-certificate-store)

Comment: While you're asking "import" and that question asks "deleting", you're both after the programmatic name of the "Other People" store, which is AddressBook.

Comment: @bartonjs, really? its AddressBook? I thought i tried them all.
I'll giva it a try tomorrow! thanks!

Comment: @bartonjs, I have tried it and it almost works. I noticed the addressbook is only available if there is already a certificate of this type installed. So addressbook isnt there on a clean windows 10 install... thats why its not working. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  But that's different enough from the current question that it should probably be a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer **AddressBook**.
This store doesn't exist if there hasn't already been installed in this store (via GUI)